# Does Alamofire support suspend operation queue when offline?

Tags: swift, httprequest, alamofire, offline-caching

I used AFNetworking library before, it can cache the http request when offline, and resume when online. Is this available in Alamofire? I tried a few time, it always returns:

> error code 1009: the internet connection appears to be offline.

Is there an way to achieve this function? Thanks.